# Java, importing a userinput

Tags: java

I'm currently in an entry Java class and my instructor has asked us to make a program. He has provided us with 3 IO classes to input into netbeans to fix some of the errors. This program is asking us to enter an employee's information and output that info to a file. When I do I get the cannot find symbol error. I placed the Keyboard class in the userinputs folder and that works fine. I'm having issues with the OutputFile. If I don't place the import at the top of the screen I get the errors on the first two lines under the main method. When I place the import at the top of the program like shown, those two errors go away but then I get the error on the import line of code. Again i'm very entry level, so my code at the bottom might be off but I have not been able to test it because of these errors. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
package practice;
import userinputs.Keyboard;      
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import userinputs.OutputFile;

/**
 *
 * @author hitztp
 */
public class Practice 
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        OutputFile payrollFile;
        payrollFile = new OutputFile("payroll.txt");
        Keyboard k;
        k = new Keyboard();
        String name, answer;
        Double payrate, hours;

        do
        {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter employee's full name.");
        name = k.readString();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter employee's payrate.");
        payrate = k.readDouble();
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter employee's hours worked.");
        hours = k.readDouble();
        payrollFile.writeString(name);
        payrollFile.writeDouble(payrate);
        payrollFile.writeDouble(hours);

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to enter another employee? (yes/no)");
        answer = k.readString();

        }while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

    payrollFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put all three IO classes in the same folder (e.g. userinputs).

Comment: You can try using an absolute path instead of a relative path. (e.g. Something like "C:\Java\userinputs\textpayroll.txt" instead of "textpayroll.txt"). The `OutputFile` class may require an absolute path.

Comment: Your mainClass is in package named practice and your other two classer are in package userinputs.Make sure  both package are under src folder.

Comment: He told us to specifically not use an absolute path, so it would write to a file in the netbeans file folder. I have both IO classes in the userinputs folder. I created a Practice project so I would not mess up my original, but the userinputs is under the Practice project and both IO's are under the userinputs.

Comment: Sorry the userinputs is under the src folder as well.

Comment: which IDE you are using and is it a simple java project or a maven project?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and its a simple java project.

Comment: try moving the MainClass to userinputs package by right-click on the java file refactor ->move and check if it solves the problem or not

Comment: M.Sharma, that didn't work either.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. Thanks for all the input. I had to do a simple tweek inside of one of the IO's to get it to work.